# jQuery Knob 0.5 steps?

Tags: jquery, jquery-knob

We want to use jQuery Knob to select values with steps from 0.5 we tried to configure
step: .5 but it does not work. In jQuery Slider this does work this way. is it possible to use this also in Knob? What is the syntax for this?

Thanks
Marco

Comment: Which jQuery Knob are you using?

Answer (score 5):

I changed mine to data-step=0.1 and it works.

```
<input  class="knob" data-bgcolor="#333" data-fgcolor="#ACD53A" data-thickness=".4" readonly data-step="0.1" value="22.5" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using this jQuery Knob (http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) use `data-step="0.5"` as seen on the **5-digit values, step 1000** demo.

Comment: i tried using 0.5 on this demo, it still uses default value of 1 for the steps.

Comment: You can not have decimal-steps yet, sorry. https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/pull/34 - There's no solution for this but getting a new plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it looks like you are probably using an old version of jquery.knob.js.

Try the version in the lilnk below

https://github.com/Aeon/jQuery-Knob/blob/0a7086e4ff1ecdf4216378a294f9d201c2388390/js/jquery.knob.js

Then you can use  data-step="0.5" in your input field.